# JavaScript mouseenter and mouseleave fade effects glitchy

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, fadein, fadeout, jquery-hover

I have made an example in JS fiddle if you hover over "Wall" for example then move your cursor over the dropdown menu which fades in below. Before you can use it, it will fadeOut then fadeIn.

I have tried using a timeout and checking if it is the same hover parent. That didn't work as when you come off it completely it would stay on.

https://jsfiddle.net/eqxDev/t49e7amz/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.places .place-link, .place_dropdown').one().on('mouseenter', function () {
    $("#place_link_" + $(this).data('placement')).addClass('hovered');
    $("#place_dropdown_" + $(this).data('placement')).addClass('hovered');
    $("#place_dropdown_" + $(this).data('placement')).fadeIn(350);
});

$('.places .place-link, .place_dropdown').one().on('mouseleave', function () {
    $("#place_link_" + $(this).data('placement')).removeClass('hovered');
    $("#place_dropdown_" + $(this).data('placement')).removeClass('hovered');
    $("#place_dropdown_" + $(this).data('placement')).fadeOut(350);
});
```

});

When hovering over the item Wall it shouldn't fadeIn then Out when you try to hover over the list of items below.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because a `mouseleave`/`mouseenter` is triggered when moving from the tab to the menu underneath. To fix this, add a `stop()` call before fading to move the animation queue to the end before adding the new animation:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.places .place-link, .place_dropdown').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var placement = $(this).data('placement');
    $("#place_link_" + placement).addClass('hovered');
    $("#place_dropdown_" + placement).addClass('hovered').stop(true).fadeIn(350);
  });

  $('.places .place-link, .place_dropdown').on('mouseleave', function() {
    var placement = $(this).data('placement');
    $("#place_link_" + placement).removeClass('hovered');
    $("#place_dropdown_" + placement).removeClass('hovered').stop(true).fadeOut(350);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.places li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 100px
}

.place_dropdown {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: -15px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="places">
  <li class="place-link" id="place_link_wall" data-placement="wall">
    <span class="icon-title">Wall</span>
  </li>
  <li class="place-link" id="place_link_floor" data-placement="floor">
    <span class="icon-title">Floor</span>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="place_dropdown" id="place_dropdown_wall" style="display: none" data-placement="wall">
  <span>Wall</span>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Test Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Page</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="place_dropdown" id="place_dropdown_floor" style="display: none" data-placement="floor">
  <span>Floor</span>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Test Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Page</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

With all that said, it's worth nothing that with a minor structural change to the HTML you could make this menu entirely in CSS.

Comment: Thank you worked. Unfortunately, the full menu which this is in I would be unable to do with CSS but thanks for the tip!